# Bootstrap sticky position doesn't stick

Tags: css, jsx, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

```
        <div className="d-flex container sticky-top">
          <div className="me-2 flex-grow-1 ms-4">
            <Posts className="me-10" />
            <Posts className="me-10" />
            <Posts className="me-10" />
            <Posts className="me-10" />
          </div>
          <div className="col">
            <GroupPage className="position-sticky" />
          </div>
        </div>
```

I want to make my `GroupPage` sticky(bootstrap), i have tried all sticky-top and it doesn't work, any solution?

Comment: Sticky position doesn't work because of flexbox.

Comment: learn bootstrap first